# style="" tag allowed in php strip_tags?

Tags: php, html

I am using the following php snippet to limit the number of html tags allowed in one of my text areas:

```
$post_content = strip_tags( $post_content, '<b>,<cite>,<em>,<i>,<u>,<s>,<strike>,<strong>,<h1>,<br>,<p>' );
```

However, I also want to allow text color changes via:

```
<span style="color: #000000">  OR <font color="#cc0000">
```

Currently, anything like this will get stripped out.

I cant find any information on this anywhere.. Is it at all possible?

Comment: I think you're confused, the tags you put into the strip_tags are the ones you want to ALLOW, not BLOCK.  You'd want something like this: **strip_tags( $post_content, '<span><font>' );**   [PHP strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Pls take care of `<span onclick="alert('hi');">click here</span>` as it will not get removed. So you are vulnerable to cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: Hello. thanks for the reply. I want to allow the tags I have included yes. But I also what to allow the tags that have style elements associated with them. Such as <span style="color: #fff"> which currently gets stripped. <b>,<h1>,<u> work fine, but <font color="#cc0000"> gets stripped. I will look in to the javascript issue too thanks

Comment: can you just add them into your strip_tags list? I don't see "span" or "font" in there